# Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object - but is an object

Tags: php, oop

I'm working on this method.

```
public function getTabs()
{
    $tabs = [];
    foreach ($this->campaigns as $index => $campaign) {

        // return $campaign->getTitle();
        // return get_class($campaign);
        // $title = $campaign->getTitle();

        // return $campaign->getTabTitle();
        // return get_class($campaign);
        // $title = $campaign->getTabTitle();

        array_push($tabs, [
                'title' => $title
            ]);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

The values in $this->campaign array, are instances of Campaign Object (for shure, due to typehinting in addCampaign method - not shown here but still).

If I would uncomment a line where I return the value rather than saving it to a variable, it works, but if I try to save it to the $title variable it throws an exception `Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object`.

I tried it also with an other method but still no luck ...

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Why does PHP make a difference here? Would like to understand this process!

Thanks already to everyone taking the time to read this! :)

Comment: `var_dump` every entry before you try to call `getTitle` on it. Simple debugging. If PHP tells you it's not an object, then it's not an object. Figure out what it is instead by inspecting it and then trace back how it got to be that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet is that one of you entry in `campaigns` is not an object. Try to do a `var_dump($this->campaings);`.

It would work if you put the return because it would stop the foreach loop after the first element, but if you store it in a variable, it will try to call the getTitle() method on all the elements of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should help you to find out what are the problem with particular items:

```
foreach ($this->campaigns as $index => $campaign) {
    var_dump(get_class($campaign));
}
```

If it won't help it would be great to take a look a the whole class. Maybe there is any other place where you are adding an item into an array. Maybe during initialization?

Comment: Hey, thx for the snippet. I already got the error. It was actually a simple one ^^. After a long day, I simply forgot the basics on debugging :P But thx for the snippet anyway, hope it helps some one else!